# How to produce isort report via XML?

Tags: python, isort

I'm trying to inject isort job into my gitlab ci pipeline and I wan't to save artifacts of my job. But I can not understand how to generate isort report via XML format.

I tried to research information about --formatter cli parameter but nothing found.

Comment: Are you asking how to have isort produce XML?  I don't think that is an option.  You can have it produce a `diff` listing.